# I am unable to extend my activity to listactivity. help needed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-listview

I am unable to extend my activity to listactivity. I want to extend it to listactivity and add onclicklistener to the list items.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lView;
    private ArrayList results = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvApps);
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List < ResolveInfo > list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo: list) {
            results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
                .loadLabel(pm).toString());
            Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
                .loadLabel(pm).toString());
        }
        lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Use **extends ListActivity** in public class MainActivity extends Activity

Comment: the code runs well aslong as i have " public class MainActivity extends Activity" but when i try changing it to "public class MainActivity extends ListActivity " so that i can use " onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)" to access the position of listitem.

i get error
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'"

Comment: the listview id in your layout must be set to android:id="@android:id/list" This is how the listactivity knows how to find your listview

Answer (score 1):

if you're gonna use a `ListActivity` then you don't need this line:

```
ListView lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvApps);
```

**BUT** that specific `ListView` being referred to right now (provided it's in the corresponding xml layout) must have it's id changed to

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following piece of code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

    private ArrayList results = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List < ResolveInfo > list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo: list) {
            results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
                .loadLabel(pm).toString());
            Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
                .loadLabel(pm).toString());
        }
                getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
    }

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

**Explaination:**

ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen.so you can directly set the adapter.

Have a look at [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) for reference

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: 05-15 17:19:52.383: E/AndroidRuntime(6370): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ku.installedapps/com.ku.installedapps.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: if you want to use listactivity,you don't need listview in xml file as per my answer but your errors says that you already have a listview in your xml file which is not having id like `android:id="@android:id/list"`.kindly look at answer given by `Manish Android` or refer the `docs` which I have linked with my answer.

Comment: my xml file and i dont have any listview in xml as yu can see
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
 
</LinearLayout>


But i m still geting error

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ku.installedapps/com.ku.installedapps.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'


:(

Comment: @mehhancy: check my updated answer,you need to avoid `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` otherwise system will go to that xml file to find the listview having id `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: Thankyou.... The problem has been solved. the problem was due to the setcontentview :) . thankyouagain

Comment: I'm glad to help,Kindly accept it as answer by clicking on accept if you are satisfied with solution.

Answer (score 0):

implement OnItemClickListener

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener
{
   //your code;

    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    results.get(pos);  //this will give you the value in the clicked list item as per your code
}
}
```

Comment: if you are using a layout with list view then you dont have to extend ListActivity you can extend activity and you can do ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourlayout);   listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);                   if you are extending ListActivty you dont have to have a layout with ListView.